# Access service definition from previous bundle in extension

Tags: php, symfony

I have two bundles A and B that are loaded in AppKernel.php (first A, then B).

**Configuration 1 (works)**

Bundle A, Extension:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $container->setParameter('test', '123');
}
```

Bundle B, Extension:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $test = $container->getParameter('test');
}
```

**Configuration 2 (works not)**

Bundle A, Extension:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');
}
```

Bundle B, Extension:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $def = $container->findDefinition('test_service');
}
```

So my question is why can I access parameters from a previous loaded bundle but not the service definitions? I know there are compiler passes, but I want to add some method calls to a definition without setting a parameter first.

Comment: I'm not sure understand the problem, but maybe the documentation can help you http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter the order in which bundles are registered in `AppKernel.php`, because in the `load()` method **doesn't get the actual container instance, but a copy**. This container only has the parameters from the actual container (not service definition from others bundle/extension). So you should seems this exception message:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "test_service".
```

After loading the copy will be merged into the actual container. [More details](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html#using-the-load-method).

---

However, you can do it in other place, only needs to implement `PrependExtensionInterface`:

```
class BExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $def = $container->findDefinition('test_service');
    }
}
```

Inside the `prepend()` method, you have full access to the `ContainerBuilder` instance just before the `load()` method is called on each of the registered bundle Extensions. So you can play with external bundle definitions there. [More details](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html).

Comment: This seems to work. I created a seperate services_prepend.yml that is loaded in the prepend function. Then I have access to the service definition.